# Не могу из объекта получить имя этого объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть JavaScript  объект

```
screen = {
  title: thisObjectName
}
```

Нужно присвоить переменной `thisObjectName` значение равное имени объекта в данном случаи это значение  равно **screen**

Comment: Это невозможно. screen это ссылка на объект, сам объект про неё ничего не знает и не может знать. Если я напишу `x = screen` у меня будет две **абсолютно одинаковых ссылки**. Какое имя вы хотите узнать "x" или "screen"?

Comment: думаю вам нужно пересмотреть подход к реализации вашей задачи

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно знать название объекта к которому непосредственно обращаетесь (и для этого костыль с `title` так может вам нужно создавать объект через функцию конструктор, а еще лучше через класс? тогда у Вас будет доступ к названию этого класса

```js
class Screen {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar'
  }
}

const inst = new Screen()

console.log(inst.foo) //bar
console.log(inst.constructor.name) //Screen
```

если Вам прям так сильно нужно знать не название класса а название переменой, которая содержит указатель на объект то можно инжектить это название через конструктор

```js
class Screen {
  constructor(name) {
    this.title = name
  }
}

const screen = new Screen('screen')

console.log(screen.title) //screen
```

но лучше напишите зачем Вам это все. Думаю есть стандартные варианты решения Вашей задачи